# Creating a dynamic table using form1 with textbox1 textbox2 textbox3, Need some suggestion

Tags: c#, sql, database, dynamic-programming

Hi i m newbie in programming, I have tried to create an application with `Form1`, which have `textbox1` `textbox2` and `textbox3` and a `CreateButton`.

Actually I m making a Database Tables Creator application using windows form.
Please help me to make it.

I want to know how to make it? I m getting an error that **Table Created failed**

```
    private void CreateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\Gaudis\Completed Projects\database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
        string qry = "PDynamicTable";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
        try
        {
            SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@tname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@col1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("@col2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            p1.Value = textbox1.Text;
            p2.Value = textbox2.Text;
            p3.Value = textbox3.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p3);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Table Created");
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Table Created failed");
            ex.ToString();

        }
        finally
        {

            con.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You can not ask for a code without providing some examples, or at least something to show that you tried anything.

Comment: I have updated the codes. please check

Comment: Instead of showing 'Table Create failed', it would me more useful to see what ex.Tostring() is.

Comment: It says incorrect syntax near PDynamicTable

Comment: Ok, so fix the syntax error. I came here for the datatables tag, but it looks like you're not using datatables at all!

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'PDynamicTable'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found solution for own question, Cannot delete my question as per t&c of this website. Posting this information to help others who are newbies just like me. :)

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\Login.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
 con.Open();
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
 cmd.Connection = con;
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES";
 SqlDataAdapter dbAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataTable dtRecords = new DataTable();
 dbAdapter.Fill(dtRecords);
 comboBox1.DataSource = dtRecords;
 comboBox1.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
 con.Close();
```